# Simple MD5 hash of a String

Tags: javascript, md5, phantomjs

How can I generate an MD5 hash of a String, from JavaScript running on PhantomJS ?

I tried `npm install -g crypto` but the crypto module is not found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PhantomJs does not natively support MD5 but you can easily inject external script code using [phantom.injectJs](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/method/inject-js.html).

You have *just* a find an implementation in javascript. MD5 is quite popular and not too difficult to implent. So there are many implementations such as [crypto-js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#MD5) or [wbond/md5-js](https://github.com/wbond/md5-js).

A very basic script using CryptoJS could be

```
var system = require('system');

if (system.args.length != 2) {
    console.log("Usage: phantomjs md5_test.js input");
} else {
    if(phantom.injectJs('md5.js')) {
        console.log(CryptoJS.MD5(system.args[1]));
        phantom.exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see, phantomjs is different than NodeJS actually, I didn't notice it really.

Comment: or: console.log(md5(system.args[1]));